# Is there another application like Nokia PC Suite for Ubuntu?

Tags: alternative, nokia

I've been looking for an alternative Nokia PC suite for Ubuntu. I'm tired of switching OS, and I'm tired of using Windows it is so boring me.

Not Wammu, Gammu, Nokuntu, Ginokki and Series 60. They don't work. Via cable. I need an application that can detect via cable (because I have a very different reason why I need it to detect via cable).

Also after installing in Wine it can't detect the Phone and I think the installation didn't finish correctly.

Thank You !